# Best way to replicate Oracles range windowing function in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to perform this Oracle query in SQL Server:

```
select case_id, channel_index,
     min(su_min) as sustained_min,
     max(su_max) as sustained_max
from (
    select case_id, channel_index, start_time,
        min(dms_value) over (partition by case_id, channel_index order by start_time 
             range numtodsinterval(3, 'minute') preceeding) as su_max,
        max(dms_value) over (partition by case_id, channel_index order by start_time 
             range numtodsinterval(3, 'minute') preceeding) as su_min, 
        min(start_time) over (partition by case_id, channel_index order by start_time)
             as first_time
    from  data_table order by start_time 
    ) as su_data
where  
    first_time + numtodsinterval(3, 'minute') <= start_time
group by
    case_id, channel_index
```

Here is what I attempted in basic T-SQL which does the job but when a case has 1 million+ records it takes more that 37 mins (after which I cancelled the query):

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetSustainedValues]( 
  @case_id int,
  @time_limit int, 
  @bypass_only bit = NULL)
as 
begin

DECLARE @time DateTime, @channelindex int, @lastchannelindex int
DECLARE @tmin float, @tmax float, @min float, @max float, @caseid int

DECLARE @results TABLE(case_id int, channel_index int, max float null, min float null)
DECLARE CursorName CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
    FOR SELECT start_time, channel_index from continuous_data where case_id = @case_id order by channel_index, start_time
OPEN CursorName
FETCH NEXT FROM CursorName INTO @time, @channelindex
SET @lastchannelindex = @channelindex
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --PRINT 'hello' --'Chennel:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @channelindex,128) + '  Time:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @time,128)
    IF @lastchannelindex != @channelindex
    BEGIN
        --PRINT 'Starting new channel:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @channelindex,128)
        -- we are starting on a new channel so insert that data into the results
        -- table and reset the min/max
        INSERT INTO @results(case_id, channel_index, max, min) VALUES(@case_id, @lastchannelindex, @max, @min)
        SET @max = null
        SET @min = null
        SET @lastchannelindex = @channelindex
    END

    Select @tmax = MAX(dms_value), @tmin = MIN(dms_value)
    from continuous_data
    where case_id = @case_id and channel_index = @channelindex and start_time between DATEADD(s, -(@time_limit-1), @time) and @time 
    HAVING SUM(value_duration) >= @time_limit
    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        IF @max IS null OR @tmin > @max
        BEGIN
            --PRINT 'Setting max:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @tmin,128) + ' for channel:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @channelindex,128)
            set @max = @tmin
        END

        IF @min IS null OR @tmax < @min
        BEGIN
            set @min = @tmax
        END
    END
    --PRINT 'Max:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @max,128) + '  Min:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @min,128)
    FETCH NEXT FROM CursorName INTO @time, @channelindex
END
CLOSE CursorName
DEALLOCATE CursorName
--PRINT 'Max:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @max,128) + '  Min:' + CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), @min,128)
SELECT * FROM @results
end
```

Is this a good place to use a CLR stored procedure? Any other ideas to make this a more efficient query?

EDIT 3-9-2012:
Don't focus on the "first_time" field. It is there to make sure that the 3 minute window starts 3 minutes into the data set. In my query I don't care about the first_time. All I need is the min/max sustained value for all 3 minute periods per channel.

Here is some sample data that contains 2 channels. Notice that the duration of each sample is not always the same:

```
CREATE TABLE #continuous_data
(
        case_id         int
    ,   channel_index   int
    ,   start_time      datetime
    ,   dms_value       float,
    ,   value_duration  smallint
)

INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   51, '2011-05-18 09:36:34.000',  90,     6)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:39.000',  94.8125,    1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:40.000',  95.4375,    1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   51, '2011-05-18 09:36:40.000',  96,     6)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:41.000',  96.75,      1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:42.000',  98.0625,    2)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:44.000',  99.3125,    1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:45.000',  100.625,    1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:46.000',  101.9375,   2)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   51, '2011-05-18 09:36:46.000',  98,     6)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:48.000',  103.25,     1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:49.000',  104.5625,   1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:50.000',  105.8125,   2)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:52.000',  107.125,    1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   51, '2011-05-18 09:36:52.000',  92,     6)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:53.000',  108.4375,   1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:54.000',  109.75,     1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:55.000',  111.0625,   2)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:57.000',  112.3125,   1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:58.000',  113.625,    1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   51, '2011-05-18 09:36:58.000',  86,     6)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:36:59.000',  114.9375,   2)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:37:01.000',  116.25,     1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:37:02.000',  117.5,      1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:37:03.000',  118.8125,   2)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   51, '2011-05-18 09:37:04.000',  80,     6)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:37:05.000',  120.125,    1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:37:06.000',  121.4375,   1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:37:07.000',  122.75,     1)
INSERT #continuous_data VALUES (2081,   50, '2011-05-18 09:37:08.000',  124.0625,   1)
```

Comment: What exactly does the Oracle query do? It appears to find the min and max dms_value and the "first_time" for each case_id/channel_index row in data_table. It would be useful to know more about the schema and functionality of the Oracle query. As for SQL, avoid the cursor and temporary table and a CLR stored procedure would be a last resort. You should be able to accomplish this with plain T-SQL without a cursor or CLR stored procedure.

Comment: SQL server doesn't have the range windows you're looking for. Could I see some sample data? There may be a way to do it with a temp table  and pure SQL.

Comment: @Ryan: because the window definition for the min() and max() contains an order by, the min() and max() values are "running" values, i.e. up to the "current row". They are not the overall min and max values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, I understand that - I meant to say "the min and max dms_value ... for the previous 3 minutes up to the current row start_time". I think it is possible to optimize both the Oracle and SQL versions more. It would be easier with sample data though.

Comment: Why is `min() over ...` aliased as `su_max` and `max() over ...` as `su_min`?

Comment: This is because the min value for the 3 minute time window is the max sustained value for that period and the max value is the min sustained value for the same period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correct, you want the following

For each case_id, channel_index combination:

1. Find the lowest MAX value for all 3 minute windows (min sustained
   value)
2. Find the highest MIN value for all 3 minutes windows (max
   sustained value).
3. Use data from the preceeding 3 minutes. If 3 minutes has not elapsed since the first (MIN) `start_time` value, exclude that data.

There are still several unexplained differences between the Oracle query and your solution (both the stored procedure and CLR stored procedure):

1. The Oracle query doesn't ensure the time difference for each window is exactly 3 minutes. It only takes the min/max value for the preceeding 3 minutes. The WHERE clause `first_time + numtodsinterval(3, 'minute') <= start_time` removes the time windows before the first 3 minutes has elapsed.
2. The `value_duration` column is in the sample data, but not used in the solution
3. The sample data does not include 3 minutes of data, so I changed the time range to 10 seconds
4. You did not list the expected results for the sample data

**SOLUTION**
-- This may not be the fastest solution, but it should work --

*Step 0*: Window Time Range -- The sample data does not include 3 minutes of data, so I used a variable to hold the desired number of seconds for the window time range. For the actual data, you could use 180 seconds.

```
DECLARE @seconds int
SET @seconds = 10
```

*Step 1*: First Time -- Although the `first_time` isn't important, it is still necessary to make sure we don't include incomplete time periods. It will be used later to exclude data before the first complete time period has elapsed.

```
-- Query to return the first_time, last_time, and range_time
-- range_time is first complete time period using the time range
SELECT  case_id 
    ,   channel_index 
    ,   MIN(start_time) AS first_time
    ,   DATEADD(ss, @seconds, MIN(start_time)) AS range_time
    ,   MAX(start_time) AS last_time
FROM    #continuous_data 
GROUP BY case_id, channel_index
ORDER BY case_id, channel_index

-- Results from the sample data
case_id     channel_index first_time              range_time              last_time
----------- ------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:36:39.000 2011-05-18 09:36:49.000 2011-05-18 09:37:08.000
2081        51            2011-05-18 09:36:34.000 2011-05-18 09:36:44.000 2011-05-18 09:37:04.000
```

*Step 2*: Time Windows -- The Oracle query uses `partition by case_id, channel_index order by start_time range numtodsinterval(3, 'minute') preceeding` to find the minimum and maximum `dms_value` as well as the `first_time` in the subquery. Since SQL Server does not have the `range` functionality, you need to use a subquery to define the 3 minute windows. The Oracle query uses `range ... preceeding`, so the SQL Server range will use `DATEADD` with a negative value:

```
-- Windowing for each time range. Window is the negative time
-- range from each start_time row
SELECT  case_id 
    ,   channel_index 
    ,   DATEADD(ss, -@seconds, start_time) AS window_start
    ,   start_time                         AS window_end
FROM    #continuous_data 
ORDER BY case_id, channel_index, start_time
```

*Step 3*: MIN/MAX for Time Windows -- Next you need to find the minimum and maximum values for each window. This is where the majority of the calculation is performed and needs the most debugging to get the expected results.

```
-- Find the maximum and minimum values for each window range
-- I included the start_time min/max/diff for debugging
SELECT  su.case_id 
    ,   su.channel_index 
    ,   win.window_end 
    ,   MAX(dms_value) AS dms_max
    ,   MIN(dms_value) AS dms_min
    ,   MIN(su.start_time) AS time_min
    ,   MAX(su.start_time) AS time_max
    ,   DATEDIFF(ss, MIN(su.start_time), MAX(su.start_time)) AS time_diff
FROM    #continuous_data AS su
   JOIN (
        -- Windowing for each time range. Window is the negative time
        -- range from each start_time row
        SELECT  case_id 
            ,   channel_index 
            ,   DATEADD(ss, -@seconds, start_time) AS window_start
            ,   start_time                         AS window_end
        FROM    #continuous_data 
    ) AS win
        ON (    su.case_id       = win.case_id
            AND su.channel_index = win.channel_index)
   JOIN (
        -- Find the first_time and add the time range
        SELECT  case_id 
            ,   channel_index 
            ,   MIN(start_time)                        AS first_time
            ,   DATEADD(ss, @seconds, MIN(start_time)) AS range_time
        FROM    #continuous_data 
        GROUP BY case_id, channel_index
    ) AS fir
        ON (    su.case_id       = fir.case_id
            AND su.channel_index = fir.channel_index)
WHERE   su.start_time BETWEEN win.window_start AND win.window_end
    AND win.window_end >= fir.range_time
GROUP BY su.case_id, su.channel_index, win.window_end
ORDER BY su.case_id, su.channel_index, win.window_end

-- Results from sample data:
case_id     channel_index window_end              dms_max                dms_min                time_min                time_max                time_diff
----------- ------------- ----------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:36:49.000 104.5625               94.8125                2011-05-18 09:36:39.000 2011-05-18 09:36:49.000 10
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:36:50.000 105.8125               95.4375                2011-05-18 09:36:40.000 2011-05-18 09:36:50.000 10
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:36:52.000 107.125                98.0625                2011-05-18 09:36:42.000 2011-05-18 09:36:52.000 10
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:36:53.000 108.4375               99.3125                2011-05-18 09:36:44.000 2011-05-18 09:36:53.000 9
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:36:54.000 109.75                 99.3125                2011-05-18 09:36:44.000 2011-05-18 09:36:54.000 10
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:36:55.000 111.0625               100.625                2011-05-18 09:36:45.000 2011-05-18 09:36:55.000 10
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:36:57.000 112.3125               103.25                 2011-05-18 09:36:48.000 2011-05-18 09:36:57.000 9
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:36:58.000 113.625                103.25                 2011-05-18 09:36:48.000 2011-05-18 09:36:58.000 10
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:36:59.000 114.9375               104.5625               2011-05-18 09:36:49.000 2011-05-18 09:36:59.000 10
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:37:01.000 116.25                 107.125                2011-05-18 09:36:52.000 2011-05-18 09:37:01.000 9
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:37:02.000 117.5                  107.125                2011-05-18 09:36:52.000 2011-05-18 09:37:02.000 10
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:37:03.000 118.8125               108.4375               2011-05-18 09:36:53.000 2011-05-18 09:37:03.000 10
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:37:05.000 120.125                111.0625               2011-05-18 09:36:55.000 2011-05-18 09:37:05.000 10
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:37:06.000 121.4375               112.3125               2011-05-18 09:36:57.000 2011-05-18 09:37:06.000 9
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:37:07.000 122.75                 112.3125               2011-05-18 09:36:57.000 2011-05-18 09:37:07.000 10
2081        50            2011-05-18 09:37:08.000 124.0625               113.625                2011-05-18 09:36:58.000 2011-05-18 09:37:08.000 10
2081        51            2011-05-18 09:36:46.000 98                     96                     2011-05-18 09:36:40.000 2011-05-18 09:36:46.000 6
2081        51            2011-05-18 09:36:52.000 98                     92                     2011-05-18 09:36:46.000 2011-05-18 09:36:52.000 6
2081        51            2011-05-18 09:36:58.000 92                     86                     2011-05-18 09:36:52.000 2011-05-18 09:36:58.000 6
2081        51            2011-05-18 09:37:04.000 86                     80                     2011-05-18 09:36:58.000 2011-05-18 09:37:04.000 6
```

*Step 4*: Finally, you can put it all together to return the lowest MAX value and highest MIN value for each time window:

```
SELECT  su.case_id 
    ,   su.channel_index 
    ,   MIN(dms_max) AS su_min
    ,   MAX(dms_min) AS su_max
FROM    (
        SELECT  su.case_id 
            ,   su.channel_index 
            ,   win.window_end 
            ,   MAX(dms_value) AS dms_max
            ,   MIN(dms_value) AS dms_min
        FROM    #continuous_data AS su
           JOIN (
                -- Windowing for each time range. Window is the negative time
                -- range from each start_time row
                SELECT  case_id 
                    ,   channel_index 
                    ,   DATEADD(ss, -@seconds, start_time) AS window_start
                    ,   start_time                         AS window_end
                FROM    #continuous_data 
            ) AS win
                ON (    su.case_id       = win.case_id
                    AND su.channel_index = win.channel_index)
           JOIN (
                -- Find the first_time and add the time range
                SELECT  case_id 
                    ,   channel_index 
                    ,   MIN(start_time)                        AS first_time
                    ,   DATEADD(ss, @seconds, MIN(start_time)) AS range_time
                FROM    #continuous_data 
                GROUP BY case_id, channel_index
            ) AS fir
                ON (    su.case_id       = fir.case_id
                    AND su.channel_index = fir.channel_index)
        WHERE   su.start_time BETWEEN win.window_start AND win.window_end
            AND win.window_end >= fir.range_time
        GROUP BY su.case_id, su.channel_index, win.window_end
) AS su
GROUP BY su.case_id, su.channel_index
ORDER BY su.case_id, su.channel_index

-- Results from sample data:
case_id     channel_index su_min                 su_max
----------- ------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
2081        50            104.5625               113.625
2081        51            86                     96
```

Comment: Let me see if that does what I want but don't focus on the "first_time" thing. It is there to make sure that the 3 minute window starts 3 minutes into the data set. In my query I don't care about the first_time. All I need is the min/max sustained value for any 3 minute period per channel.

Comment: Just tested this on my dataset and the min/max values are not coming out right. It looks like you are only looking at the first 3 minute window for each channel. What I need is the lowest MAX value for all 3 minute windows (min sustained value) and the highest MIN value for all 3 minutes windows (max sustained value).

Comment: In the future, you should describe your issue better. For example, you still haven't mentioned how many rows you expect in return and the desired windowing function was not described well either. Basically, how many rows do you expect and what results to you expect from your sample data?

The first_time subquery is essentially determining the windowing and can be modified to your needs. It should modified to return all possible 3 minute windows, and then the rest of the query should be easy.

Comment: The sample data will contain 100's of millions of rows of data. There will be 1000's of data points per channel, up to 20 channels per case and 1000's of cases in that table. I need to work on the data on a per case basis which should return around 1.5 million data points. The output of the query should contain 1 row/channel with the min/max sustained values. Clearly you know more about how that query works than I do (it was solution from another question). I do not have access to Oracle, hence my question. Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

What if you were to do something like:

```
SELECT dt2.case_id, dt2.channel_index, dtf.first_time, su_qry.su_min, su_qry.su_max
  FROM (SELECT   dt.case_id, dt.channel_index, dt.start_time, MIN (dms_value) AS su_min, MAX (dms_value) AS su_max
            FROM data_table dt
                 INNER JOIN
                 (SELECT case_id, channel_index, start_time, dateadd ('mi', start_time, -3) AS start_time_minus_3
                    FROM data_table) dtr
                 ON (    dt.case_id = dtr.case_id
                     AND dt.channel_index = dtr.channel_index
                     AND dt.start_time >= dtr.start_time_minus_3
                     AND dt.start_time <= start_time
                    )
        GROUP BY dt.case_id, dt.channel_index, dt.start_time) su_qry
       INNER JOIN
       (SELECT   case_id, channel_index, MIN (start_time)
            FROM data_table dt
        GROUP BY case_id, channel_index) dtf ON (su_qry.case_id = dtf.case_id AND su_qry.channel_index = dtf.channel_index)
       INNER JOIN data_table dt2 ON (su_qry.case_id = dt2.case_id AND su_qry.channel_index = dt2.channel_index)
 WHERE dateadd ('mi', dtf.first_time, 3) <= dt2.start_time
```

Not 100% on this, but I think this may give you what you are looking for.
Essentially, we find the min and max for the past 3 minutes for each row on the data table by doing a greater-than and less-than join. We join those results to our "first time" computation, and finally to the main table for your WHERE predicate.

Comment: I forgot a group by in the query, just added it.

Comment: Just added a sample data set to the question. It isn't 3 minutes worth so change the time window to 15 seconds or something. I also tested this query. Having a little hard time following the logic but just running it against a case with 670 records, your query returns 237,052 rows.

Comment: Just got back from vacation - do you have a solution for this? I can look into the data set if you don't have anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is a CLR stored proc that solves the problem. This returns an the sustained min/max from a case containing 1.1 million records in about 3:05 (minutes). Please let me know if there is a plain T-SQL way to accomplish this as I would rather not go down this road. However, comments on how to speed this one up would also be appreciated.

```
public partial class StoredProcedures
{
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void ComputeCaseSustainedChannelValues(int caseId, int seconds)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection("context connection=true");
        con.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("Select channel_index, start_time, dms_value, value_duration from continuous_data where case_id = {0} and dms_type = 0 and error_code is NULL order by channel_index, start_time", caseId), con);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        Queue<ContinuousData> window = new Queue<ContinuousData>();
        ArrayList channelValues = new ArrayList();
        float? sus_min = null, sus_max = null;
        float? min = null, max = null;
        int currentChannel = -1;
        bool recalc = true;
        int recalccounter = 0;
        int rowcounter = 0;
        using (reader)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var cd = new ContinuousData
                    {
                        ChannelIndex = reader.GetInt16(0),
                        StartTime = reader.GetDateTime(1),
                        DmsValue = (float)reader.GetSqlDouble(2),
                        Duration = reader.GetInt16(3)
                    };

                // check to make sure we are on the same channel. If not 
                // clear the queue and start over with the new channel
                if (currentChannel != cd.ChannelIndex)
                {
                    if (currentChannel != -1)
                    {
                        SqlContext.Pipe.Send(String.Format("Channel: {0}  Min: {1}  Max: {2}", currentChannel, sus_min, sus_max));
                    }
                    currentChannel = cd.ChannelIndex;
                    window.Clear();
                    sus_max = null;
                    sus_min = null;
                    recalc = true;
                }
                rowcounter++;
                window.Enqueue(cd);

                if (cd.StartTime.Subtract(window.Peek().StartTime).TotalSeconds >= seconds)
                {
                    if (recalc)
                    {
                        recalccounter++;
                        // a current sustained min max value was removed so recalc the window's min max
                        MinMax(window.ToArray(), out min, out max);
                        recalc = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // update the rolling min max based on the new value coming in
                        max = max == null || cd.DmsValue > max ? cd.DmsValue : max;
                        min = min == null || cd.DmsValue < min ? cd.DmsValue : min;
                    }

                    // update the sustained min max based on the current window's min max
                    sus_min = sus_min == null || max < sus_min ? max : sus_min;
                    sus_max = sus_max == null || min > sus_max ? min : sus_max;

                    // now that we calculated remove the first item
                    var firstitem = window.Dequeue();
                    if (firstitem.DmsValue == sus_min || firstitem.DmsValue == sus_max ||
                        firstitem.DmsValue == min || firstitem.DmsValue == max)
                    {
                        recalc = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (sus_max != null && sus_min != null)
        {
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(String.Format("Channel: {0}  Min: {1}  Max: {2}", currentChannel, sus_min, sus_max));
        }
        window.Clear();
        window = null;

        SqlContext.Pipe.Send(String.Format("Rows: {0}, Recalcs performed: {1}", rowcounter, recalccounter));
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Done!");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
}

private static void MinMax(ContinuousData[] cd, out float? min, out float? max)
{
    min = cd[0].DmsValue;
    max = cd[0].DmsValue;

    for (int i = 0; i < cd.Length; i++)
    {
        if (min > cd[i].DmsValue)
            min = cd[i].DmsValue;
        if (max < cd[i].DmsValue)
            max = cd[i].DmsValue;
    }
}

public class ContinuousData
{
    public int ChannelIndex { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public float DmsValue { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
}

public class ChannelValues
{
    public int ChannelIndex { get; set; }
    public float SustainedMin { get; set; }
    public float SustainedMax { get; set; }
}
};
```